# "Can not parse attribute value as date" in Nifi UpdateAttribute processor

Tags: apache-nifi

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<template encoding-version="1.3">
    <description></description>
    <groupId>de9048c5-0171-1000-4355-5efd185aa6ad</groupId>
    <name>Update_Attribute_Date</name>
    <snippet>
        <processors>
            <id>61a62c99-d8fc-3810-0000-000000000000</id>
            <parentGroupId>b055aedb-ad9e-374d-0000-000000000000</parentGroupId>
            <position>
                <x>0.0</x>
                <y>0.0</y>
            </position>
            <bundle>
                <artifact>nifi-update-attribute-nar</artifact>
                <group>org.apache.nifi</group>
                <version>1.11.4</version>
            </bundle>
            <config>
                <bulletinLevel>WARN</bulletinLevel>
                <comments></comments>
                <concurrentlySchedulableTaskCount>1</concurrentlySchedulableTaskCount>
                <descriptors>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Delete Attributes Expression</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>Delete Attributes Expression</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Store State</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>Store State</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Stateful Variables Initial Value</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>Stateful Variables Initial Value</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>canonical-value-lookup-cache-size</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>canonical-value-lookup-cache-size</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>created_date</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>created_date</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>modified_date</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>modified_date</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>schema.name</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>schema.name</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>statement.type</key>
                        <value>
                            <name>statement.type</name>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                </descriptors>
                <executionNode>ALL</executionNode>
                <lossTolerant>false</lossTolerant>
                <penaltyDuration>30 sec</penaltyDuration>
                <properties>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Delete Attributes Expression</key>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Store State</key>
                        <value>Do not store state</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>Stateful Variables Initial Value</key>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>canonical-value-lookup-cache-size</key>
                        <value>100</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>created_date</key>
                        <value>${created_date:toDate("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"):toNumber():format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")}</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>modified_date</key>
                        <value>${modified_date:toDate("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"):toNumber():format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")}</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>schema.name</key>
                        <value>village</value>
                    </entry>
                    <entry>
                        <key>statement.type</key>
                        <value>${cdc.event.type}</value>
                    </entry>
                </properties>
                <runDurationMillis>0</runDurationMillis>
                <schedulingPeriod>0 sec</schedulingPeriod>
                <schedulingStrategy>TIMER_DRIVEN</schedulingStrategy>
                <yieldDuration>1 sec</yieldDuration>
            </config>
            <executionNodeRestricted>false</executionNodeRestricted>
            <name>Schema=village &amp; Statement Type</name>
            <relationships>
                <autoTerminate>false</autoTerminate>
                <name>success</name>
            </relationships>
            <state>RUNNING</state>
            <style/>
            <type>org.apache.nifi.processors.attributes.UpdateAttribute</type>
        </processors>
    </snippet>
    <timestamp>06/13/2020 22:39:36 IST</timestamp>
</template>
```

I am trying to insert records from source to destination db using the CaptureChangeMySQL processor. Date value from source  table "2020-03-31 23:08:47" is getting changed to a format "Tue Mar 31 23:08:47 IST 2020" when processed in "CaptureChangeMySQL". The change value could not be loaded in the destination table since the data type is DateTime and getting an error "truncation due to length". So I am trying to convert the input value to correct format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" in the "UpdateAttribute" processor. Getting error as in the attachment. Please suggest how this issue could be fixed. [image: Input Json][image: Attribute Exception]

Comment: You should update the post with screen shot of your configuration for updateAttribute.

Comment: @steven-dfheinz Still getting the same error,  updateAttribute configuration has been attached.

Comment: When a flowfile is in the Q before updateAttribute is an attribute named create_date set?   I suspect it is not.   The expression language below is correct syntax.  It only works if ${testDate} or in your case ${created_date} is already set as an attribute.   Your error is saying it is not a valid value to parse as a date.

Comment: @steven-dfheinz my purpose is to convert a value for a key created_date from JSON which is created by CaptureChangeMySQL. My flow is capturechangemysql -> RouteonAttribute -> GetTablename -> JoltTransformJson ->  Update attribue ->  Putdatabaserecord. As of now I have added "EvaluteJsonPath" before UpdateAttribute". Suggest how it could be handled.

Comment: I assume the json is in the content of the flowfile.  This is where you use evaluate json, and create key value pairs from the json.  For example: (key) created_date $.createddate (value).   You need to map all the values.   Now you use updateAttribute as explained in the answer, and get the attribute created_date updated to the correct value.   Next you use AttributesToJson directed to flowfile-content with all the attributes to recreate the entire json object.   Please accept the solution, as this is the answer to your question.

Comment: @steven-dfheinz Yes, you are right, but still I am getting   error,   Unable to evaluate new value for attribute 'modifieddate': org.apache.nifi.attribute.expression.language.exception.IllegalAttributeException: Cannot parse attribute value as a date; date format: EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy; attribute value.
Could you share your configuration for updateAttribute test which you have done, so that I could try to compare if there is an error in my configuration.

Comment: @steven-dfheinz I found the error in the updateAttribue configuration, when i configure like "${created_date:toDate("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"):toNumber():format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")}" I am getting error, but when I configure like ${created_date.value:toDate("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"):toNumber():format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")} I am not getting error but my values are not getting changed. I tired using updaterecord processor the conversion worked perfectly. I need to make this work in updateAttribute processor also.

Comment: Ahh yes, nice progress.   Depending on the source json, you may need to add array mapping to the object.... like this:  created_date is $[0].created_date in EvaluateJsonPath (do alll the json values like this), then ${created_date:toDate("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"):toNumber():format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")} in updateAttribute...

Comment: I have edited my original reply with the correct values and linked a template you can reference

Comment: @steven-dfheinz Thanks, will check. I tried testing with updateRecord processor it worked without number conversion. ${field.value:toDate("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"):format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")}

Comment: @steven-dfheinz, I am having one more issue in ingesting the data in the destination table. I could not convert the value for column "status" which has bit value 0 and in son as {}. Please let me know how to handle this.

Comment: I see status is {} in the original sample data. What do you need it to be?   You can always change it with updateAttribute:    ${status:replace('{}','SomethingElse')}

Comment: @steven-dfheinz I need to know how to handle a "BIT" data type value from MySQL. When input value for the "status" (BIT data type) column in MySQL is "1" I am getting {0} in JSON and for "0' I am getting {}. Is there any other way to convert the received value to bit value i.e. 0 or 1 other than replace method.

Comment: @steven-dfheinz When I try to convert using "replace" with values "0" or "False" I am getting "Null" for the column status in the destination table.

Comment: @steven-dfheinz when i use this pattern ${ status:equals("{0}"):ifElse("TRUE","FALSE") }, I always get "FALSE".

Comment: Is ${status} defined when you execute the expression language?   Work on a micro test outside of your flow.  GenerateFlowFIle->UpdateAttribute1->UpdateAttribute2->Output Port (for all routes).  Trigger the GenerateFlowFile to create a single test, and inspect the Q for flowfile attributes as you step through the micro test.   In updateAttribute1 set status1 = {}, set status2 = {0},  now in UpdateAttribute2, test your logic on status1 or status2 until you see the desired behavior.  Once you are confident in the expression you want, take it back to your real flow...

Comment: @steven-dfheinz Value for status is being received from MySQL "bit" data type column as {} when the  column value is "0" and {0}  when the column value is "1". I will try the micro-test also.

Comment: Right. I understand,  I am not sure about how to control what comes from mysql for that data type...  but its common to manually make replacements to prepare data in nifi... In your flow you need to get $[0].status,  then in another proc downstream, ${status:replace('a','b')...so if you if else isn't working,  micro test til it does...  sometimes in nifi expression language even a single char can throw it off...

Comment: Ok, I will try testing with other options.

Comment: @steven-dfheinz I got the expected result, I made mistake in the expression. It should be ${field.value:equals("{0}"):ifElse("TRUE","FALSE")}  in "UpdateRecord" processor. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Ganesh Kumar the expression language you are looking for is as follows:

```
${testValue:toDate("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"):toNumber():format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")}
```

In my NiFi test, I set testValue = "Tue Mar 31 23:08:47 IST 2020" in updateAttribute 1, then direct to another updateAttribute 2.    I did notice that my output is 3 hours off, but suspect that is just my local timezone difference.

The flowfile Output is:

```
test1
2020-03-31 21:08:47.000

testValue
Tue Mar 31 23:08:47 IST 2020
```

**Edited 6/17/2020 After Comments Above:**

Access your json array in EvaluateJsonPath for each element as follows:

```
$[0].created_date
```

Then use the ${created_date} attribute with the Expression Language we tested above in updateAttribute as follows:

```
${created_date:toDate("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"):toNumber():format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")}
```

You can find a template demo at (right side flow): 
https://github.com/steven-dfheinz/NiFi-Templates/blob/master/NiFI_EvaluateJsonPath_Demo.xml